# Do not compile t4 file

Tags: visual-studio, t4

Suddenly, after doing a TFS 2010 get, Visual Studio 2010 is attempting to compile my .tt file as if it was c#.

Moreover, anytime I set it to "Build Action=None", Build Action gets mysteriously reset to Compile.  This is breaking our builds on the desktop.  I can get builds to work on the desktop by closing then reopening VS.

Our builds on TFS are totally broken because of this.   What to do?

The template generates a (totally ok) c# file, so I need the project to build.

I tried changing the file extension from .tt to .donotbuilddammit but that had no effect.

Comment: What is the 'CustomTool' property set to?

Comment: TFS for *the blind leading the blind* compilation. I had so much pain in the past related to TFS I'm not considering it at least for another 2 versions.

Comment: Custom tool = TextTemplatingFileGenerator

Comment: @Robert Koritnik - Likewise, but TFS 2010, once installed (there were some SharePoint integration issues if you want all that) it works a treat.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Are you by chance using the Clairus T4 plugin (or another T4 intellisense provider)?

If so, try making sure the files are not open when you change the BuildAction setting.

> Visual Studio builds intellisense
>   based on the compile action of your
>   files. It will only provide
>   intellisense for files that are marked
>   as "compile". Because of that, we
>   change the build action when the file
>   is open, and we change it back to
>   whatever it was before when checking
>   in, closing the file, closing Visual
>   Studio and also when opening Visual
>   Studio (in case it crashed)

See: http://forums.clariusconsulting.net/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=445